How to check DB status in AWS Code pipeline before deployment
I have successful integrated AWS Code Pipeline with elastic beanstalk. ECS have nestjs project running. Now I got some new feature, of background job in my project, but i do not want the job suddenly get cancelled/closed when a new code change is pushed on github that will trigger code pipeline.
What i thought to play with 2 status, enableJob and isJobRunning.
one new code change is pushed,
CodePipeline will have to check status on DB for isJobRunning, and disable enableJob.
once job is completed and isJobRunning status is false, then it will start deployment.
This is what i thought, but i m not sure how to do in code pipeline or even it is possible..
Any other recommendation would be appreciated.
